# How to get the image path of an image in MS Access 2016?

Tags: image, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a MS Access 2013 developed application. When it is opened using MS Access 2016, the jpg images are not showing.

I have seen many articles in net that it is a bug and it shows only bmp images.

My issue is I do not know the path of the JPG image which is supposed be to showed in Application.

> In property Sheet window of image,in Picture field, I can see only
>   "imagename.jpg"

. Not the path from it is loaded.

[image]

> Is there any way to find the image path from this?

note: I am new to MS Access. Any help is appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The picture is embedded, and the Picture property is just informative.

Even if you set it to the full path of the picture file, only the filename is left back, when the form is saved.